# What is `using A = struct A{};` good for in C++?

Tags: c++, struct, using

I found the construct

```
using A = struct A{};
```

in a C++ code base. What is this good for? My guess would be that `using A` has no effect at all in this context.

Comment: Sometimes there’s confusing, legal C++ `namespace A {
    int A = 23;
    struct A {
        int A = 4;
    };
}` but with using there’s an error `namespace A {
    int A = 23;
    using A = struct A {
        int A = 4;
    };
}`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As for why it's valid C++, I would imagine that is due to parity with `typedef`. Many a C code base have something like this:

```
typedef struct A {
  // ...
} A;
```

This is valid C, and for compatibility's sake, the C++ standard has verbiage to accept this construct (which has little effect). Since a type alias declaration with `using` is meant to be exactly the same as the equivalent `typedef`, the validity of what you saw is likely an emergent property.

As for why you saw it, it may just be a C-ism (which often make their way into C++ code) that got translated into "Modern C++". That is of course silly, and a simple structure declaration will do if the code is meant to be C++-only<sup>1</sup>.

---

<sub><sup>1</sup> - The C standard *did* add a bunch of features in C23 for increased parity with C++ code. I'm not aware of any plans to allow modern C++ type aliases in C, but assuming there were any, that construct may then be used for compatibility too.</sub>

Comment: There is a *small* difference, such as `stat()` function and `struct stat{};` structure, as affordance to C code compiled with a C++ compiler. Doing a `typedef struct stat stat;` would cause a collision, since the `struct` "namespace" (for lack of a better term) is second fiddle to the namespace for name lookup, but the `typedef` puts the new identifier in the current namespace.

Comment: @Eljay - `typedef struct stat stat;` would cause a collision in both C *and* C++. So in that regard, it's still the same compatibility layer in effect. I guess there's the other half, that where `stat` is hidden in C++ by another declaration of the same name in the same scope. But I'm not sure what your comment is aiming at.

Comment: Just commenting about the (rare) collision danger of `typedef` (or of `using`).